# Angular 8 baseUrl gets wiped out

Tags: javascript, php, angular, kohana, angular8

What we try to do is integrate and angular app in a PHP environment.
So the site will completely run on PHP for the static context, only when the user clicks on login, the will end up in the angular part.

So, now the problem. 
When we enter the URL in PHP, it will be something like `...domain/nl/page`.
So far so good, and this get redirected to angular, also this works, angular load.
But then angular deletes the last part of the link and changes it to

```
...domain/{pageThatAngularIsIn}.
```

This is where we want to keep the language en the URL should be

```
.../domain/nl/{pageThatAngularIsIn} or even 
.../domain/nl/page/{pageThatAngularIsIn}  -> step by step
```

So angular should ignore the language part in the URL but also not wipe it form the URL.

Anybody know if this is possible of why this happens?

Comment: Did you have a look at Base Href in the production of angular app. Have a look at the link below - https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag

Comment: Yes, I have set my base href, but for some reason it get wiped.... The base href is set dynamicly in php, so It's not a parameter during the build

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably happening because Angular thinks that `domain/` is the base route on which it should append its own routing.  From your description, it sounds like you wan the base route to be `domain/nl/` instead.

This is a simple fix.  In the `index.html` file that has your angular root component embedded, look for a `base` element in the head and set it to the base path.  By default, it's usually something like this:

```
<base href="/">
```

Experiment with it to get what you need.  Perhaps:

```
<base href="/nl">
```

[See the docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag)

If you will need to use that same base within your angular app, for instance to make http calls in a way that will use the same base, you should probably use the `APP_BASE_HREF` in your root module providers instead.  Like:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/nl'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

With this you will be able to inject the base in your services, for example to make your http calls.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private baseHref: string
  ) {}

  getRecords() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseHref + '/records')
  }
}
```

[See the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast replay. This was my first thought too, so my base href is allready set to "/nl", and still it get wiped off... But I didn't instert it in to my root module, because my api call (and assets, images...) are all on the main domain..
So for the api I need to call ...domain/api/..., images ...domain/assets/imgs.. but for the routing I need ... domain/nl/{pageofangular}...;

Is this even possible or am I looking for something that's not possible?